# How to URL rewrite a moved site from wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I moved my site from wordpress to another platform.  I tried to rewrite the old urls without success.

previously I had url structures similar to examples down below...

- domain.com/category/post-name.html
- domain.com/category/page-name
- domain.com/category/post-2010-name.html
- domain.com/2011/02/16/post-name.html
- domain.com/2011/02/16/page-name

as you can see above sometimes the postname had a number to it.  Also, pages and posts were listed with dates.

the new url structure is...

- domain.com/brand-new-section/blog/

**so old url...**
domain.com/mobile-phones/new-iphone-5-maps-issue.html

**should map to...**
domain.com/brand-new-section/blog/mobile-phones/new-iphone-5-maps-issue

so, I did the url rewrite for dates...

> RewriteRule ^/[0-9]+/[0-9]+/[0-9]+/(.*)?$ domain.com/brand-new-section/blog/$1 [R=301,NC,L]

Any suggestions?

how can I combine the above url rewrite with other rewrite rules such as...
 domain.com/category/post-name.html 
 
domain.com/category/post-2010-name.html

tried...

> RewriteRule ^/[0-9]+/[0-9]+/[0-9]+/(.*)?$ http://www.domain.com/brand-new-section/blog/$1[R]
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/[a-zA-z]+/[a-zA-z]+/(.*)?\.html$
>
> RewriteRule ^/[a-zA-z]+/[a-zA-z]+/(.*)?\.html$ http://www.domain.com/brand-new-section/blog/$1 [R=301,NC,L]

no success.

thank you.

Comment: Can you give examples of the different types of URL structure you had previously, and the new structure you want them to map to?

Comment: main url structure was **domain.com/category/post-name.html**, however I added other url structures that were used... please, let me know if you have any other questions.  Thank you.